# How to obtain ec2 AMI pricing info. using CLI/URL

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am struggling to understand how to obtain pricing info. programmatically (that is, via URL or aws CLI). I suspect
I am missing the 'big picture'.

I can estimate pricing manually on the web by, for example, aws marketplace -> operating systems -> select an AMI -> instance type.
This gives an estimate cost.

I would like to do the same via the aws CLI or URL.

I want to compare costs for a variety of regions & instance types but this is too time consuming to explore manually.

To be specific, given an instance obtained using `aws ec2 describe-images --owners aws-marketplace`, how do I go about mapping this to the data in an offer file obtained using, for
example, `wget https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json`?

Any suggestions appreciated (or redirect to more appropriate site).

Answer (score 2):

There is an `aws cli pricing` command  which returns a ton of information.  I didn't find it to be very helpful by itself but if you ran it through `jq` it could give you what you're looking for.  Here's the link to the docs.    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/pricing/index.html

I do not see a way to get information from the `describe-images` api that will allow you to price ec2 instances out.  The results from the call do not contain an Instance Type.

I also found a similar question on Stack Overflow with some great references to the API calls you mentioned but it doesn't discuss the cli.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334035/get-ec2-pricing-programmatically

Comment: Thanks Ken; I had tried the `aws pricing` command with various subcommands such as `get-products`, `describe-services`, `get-attribute-values`, but could not find a way to do via CLI what I can easily do manually via the web :-(.

Comment: Also, nice find. I thought I had looked at every related question :-).